# Hover state on current menu item

Tags: css, wordpress

I ran into a little problem that seems to be a pain in the ass to fix. I have styled this wordpress menu http://bandmark.com and every menu item has its own background image. The problem I am having is that I cannot remove or overwrite the style that controls the ".current" background. On the home page they look fine but if you click a link to go to a page/category then the .current style kicks in and messes with the presentation. When you hover over the current menu item the graphic slides in at a weird angle and does not look very good.

```
    nav#omc-main-navigation ul li.current-menu-item a
```

seems to be element that I need to override. If I change the background to none I get a blank  screen. Anyway to get the .current state to be the same as :hover? Like I said above they all have their own menu-item-{number}. I apologize if this sounds a bit confusing.

Comment: You have a <li> with an anchor <a> inside. I inspected those elements in Chrome (using right-click -> inspect) and if I disable the background color of the <a> which is inside the `li.current-menu-item`, then the animation behaves normally. It's weird. You must be messing with the background properties (positions) of the current-menu-item children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you've defined the hover states, e.g.:

```
nav#omc-main-navigation ul li#menu-item-4200 a:hover { background: ... }
```

add the current menu item as follows:

```
nav#omc-main-navigation ul li#menu-item-4200 a:hover,
nav#omc-main-navigation ul li#menu-item-4200.current-menu-item a { background: ... }
```

Comment: Note: if you have subpages/posts, it's also a good idea to add `nav#omc-main-navigation ul li#menu-item-4200.current-menu-parent a`, `nav#omc-main-navigation ul li#menu-item-4200.current-post-ancestor a` and `nav#omc-main-navigation ul li#menu-item-4200.current-category-ancestor a` to cover all the bases.

Comment: This is similar to what I did. I actuallu did this 'nav#omc-main-navigation ul li.current-menu-item#menu-item-11 a, nav#omc-main-navigation ul li#menu-item-11 a:hover' I am not sure how to make the code format but thank you for your help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Can you just add .current to the :hover style?  Example:

```
a:hover, a .current { background-color: #333; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e2vTN/